# How to replace success:function() with .done() in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, syntax, deprecated

I was told that `success:function()` is deprecated and I should use `.done()` instead. However, I don't know how to properly replace it in my ajax code. I'm sure it's a simple fix.

Can you please show me what this code should look like? Thank you

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "confirm.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data: {name: $('#name').val(), submitter: 'yes' },
                success: function(data)
           {
              $("#mainForm").hide();
             $('#thankYou').show();
           }

       })
```

Comment: `$.ajax(...).done(function(data) { ... })`. You can find examples in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `success` property is *not* deprecated, and there is no need to change the code. That is a misconception coming from the `jqXHR.success` method being deprecated.

Anyhow, this is how you would use the `done` method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "confirm.php",
  dataType:"text",
  data: {name: $('#name').val(), submitter: 'yes' }
}).done(function(data) {
  $("#mainForm").hide();
  $('#thankYou').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`done` function is chained in jQuery. It looks like:

```
$.ajax(
 //ajax stuffs
 ...
 ...
).done(function(){
 // after ajax completion
});
```